# How to handle changing a String attribute to a mapped Entity with JPA in a working application

Tags: jpa

Is there a way to show the FK in an Entity when a mapped entity is Null?

---

I have a working JSF application with an entity that had a string (widget_id) we wanted to track.

Now we want to track other attributes associated with the widget_id so I changed my Entity from

```
private String widget_id;
```

to

```
@Entity
public class Sprocket
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="widget_id", referencedColumnName = "widget_id")
private Widget widget;
```

Of course there were already a bunch of Sprockets persisted with FK widget_id's that are not listed in the Widget table so when I view those Sprockets I don't see the String or FK anymore because the mapping is null.

How should this be handled? Obviously one fix is to run an insert query and back fit the widget_id into the Widget table.  Are there any other tricks for this scenario?  I tried a few things on the mapping and queries to show the FK when the mapping was null but no luck.

With the cascade, any newly persisted Sprockets will handle persisting a new Widget. So going forward should not be an issue.

Comment: How does this question relate to jsf? You should reduce the question to either JPA or JSF. If necessary, ask 2 questions, but you should not mix them

Comment: And how is this hibernate specific related instead of plain jpa? Do you not have a proglem when using eclipslink?